# How to check installed third party plugin in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I have a website built in magento,and  i want to update the version of magento before that i want to check all the installed third party plugins like ebay.

Comment: Not sure what your question is?

Comment: If you are asking on "How to check which extensions are installed?"
You can check like
-
admin > system > configuration > advanced > (List of all modules)
& the another way is 
admin > system > magento connect > magento connect manager > (Login & you will be able to see list of extension installed)

Comment: sorry if i wan't clear enough with the question above,my issues is i want to update my magento website from 1.6 to 2.0 .
before updating i want to check all the third party plugin used in my website.
like courier company plugin is integrated for shipment,where can i find that ?

Comment: First, contact **all** your module developers and find out if they have Magento 2.0 modules available. Most won't, it's too early in the game. Magento 2.0 requires complete module rewrites and NONE of your Magento 1.0 modules will work, so upgrading them **will not** make your site ready for Magento 2.0 MIGRATION.

Answer (score 2):

You can find versions of your magento installed extensions in several places:

**First method :**

You could browse through `app/code/local` and `app/code/community`. For each module go to `etc/` and open `config.xml`.

On top of the file there is a module definition tag containing the version of the module such as :

```
<modules>
    <Company_Module>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Company_Module>
</modules>
```

**Second method**

If you can access your magento database, look for `core_resource`table.
There you will have listed all magento module and their version number in column named `version`. Looks like this :

```
code                        version    data_version
adminnotification_setup     1.6.0.0     1.6.0.0
admin_setup                 1.6.1.1     1.6.1.1
all_setup                   0.1.3       0.1.3
api2_setup                  1.0.0.0     1.0.0.0
api_setup                   1.6.0.1     1.6.0.1
```